# por que al entrar al while imprime las dos preguntas a la vez sin esperar el escaner?

Tags: java

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]> Este es el ejercicio : > > Crear una lista de jugadores de futbol. > En dicha lista se guardaran objetos de la clase Jugador, > que tendrá los atributos nombre, de tipo Sting y dorsal de tipo int. > Solicitar los datos de los jugadores por teclado, y una vez introducido el primero > , se insertara en la lista y se preguntara si se desea introducir otro más, > para lo cual el usuario escribirá S o N. En caso afirmativo se volverá a pedir otro más, > hasta que el usuario escriba N > > al darle "s" de continuar entra al while y me imprime dos println a la > vez sin esperar al escaner, no se que me esta faltando > > mi codigo :

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");
        nombre.add(sc.nextLine());
        
        System.out.println("Introduzca su dorsal: ");
        dorsal.add(sc.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Desea seguir agregando s/n ? :");
        op = sc.next().charAt(op);

    } while (op=='s');
    
    sc.close();

    System.out.println("culminado");
    System.out.println(jugador);
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás planteando mal tu solución. Cuando creas un bucle do-while, lo que va dentro del bucle se repite mientras no se cumpla la condición del while.

Tal y como lo tienes, en el momento en que el usuario introduce 's' finaliza el bucle y se pinta lo que está a continuación (por eso te aparece dos veces la pregunta).

Deberías reestructurarlo... Una alternativa (basándome en tu código):

```
do {
    System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");
    nombre.add(sc.nextLine());      
    System.out.println("Introduzca su dorsal: ");
    dorsal.add(sc.nextInt());       
    System.out.println("Desea seguir agregando s/n ? :");
    op = sc.next().charAt(op);
} while (op=='s');

System.out.println("Gracias por usar nuestro programa hasta luego");

sc.close();
System.out.println(jugador);
```

Es decir, mientras el usuario seleccione 's' se seguirá repitiendo lo que está dentro del bucle. Si pulsa otra tecla, se terminará.

Podrías mejorarlo para controlar que si lo introducido no es 's' o 'n' continúe pidiendo insertar un valor válido. :)

Un saludo!

Comment: gracias por aclararme el do while pero aun me salen las dos preguntas a la vez

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que al usar un *nextLine()*, se queda "pegado" el botón de enter. Lo cual hace que para tu siguiente pregunta para ingresar el dorsal se lea directamente el enter. Una solución practica bastaria con llamar dos veces la entrada de datos. La primera para que reconozca el enter y lo "limpie" y la segunda vez para que ya pueda hacer la lectura.

El codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");
    nombre.add(sc.nextLine());      
    System.out.println("Introduzca su dorsal: ");
    dorsal.add(sc.nextInt()); //Captura el enter
    dorsal.add(sc.nextInt()); //Aca lees el valor    
    System.out.println("Desea seguir agregando s/n ? :");
    op = sc.next().charAt(op);
} while (op=='s');
```

Ojo que este tipo de problematicas suele suceder cuando cambias el metodo de lectura de datos. Por lo tanto tambien se repite cuando realizas el cambio del *sc.next()* al *sc.nextLine()*